# Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 631988

Tags: matlab

I got error

```
"Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 631988"
```

When try to find the problem I notice that it belong to index is like over 631988 even the empty row in table is after 631988 as shown in attached screenshot

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7hjq.png)

The error is related to this line in code becouse I put index to 1000000
so how can make it depend on index of table

```
Data='tabledata.txt';
[Arrivals]=importdata(Data);
Arrivalsdata=Arrivals(:,1);

for i=2:1000000
 Interarrivalptk(i-1)=Arrivalsdata(i)-Arrivalsdata(i-1);
end
```

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `Arrivalsdata` is a 631988x1 double. Displaying an empty row 631989 does not mean that there is data in it or that it is allocated. Why do you want to specify 1,000,000 rows instead of the actual size of the array?

Comment: Thank you for replay, I use it for data above 1,000,000 but I ask if possible to be depends on variable instead of make it fixed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your question. The edit makes it much more understandable. I will also point out that your loop could be replaced by [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you want to only loop over the Arrivalsdata array.
Something like this:

```
Data='tabledata.txt';
[Arrivals]=importdata(Data);
Arrivalsdata=Arrivals(:,1);

for i=2:length(Arrivalsdata)
 Interarrivalptk(i-1)=Arrivalsdata(i)-Arrivalsdata(i-1);
end
```

Comment: thank  you it works